# FFMpeg How can i add an image and text to other video with moving background

Tags: ffmpeg

How can i make something like this:
https://courtyard.io/asset/d624168fe54977ee1f91639fd7d4c70ca003f6cd750ed4e89a852dfec700deda

Where the text and the card is added in by ffmpeg or other program? The challenge here is i would like to program it. So when a user uploads an jpeg and adds text we generate this video.